# How can I select data from a dask dataframe by a list of indices?

Tags: python, indexing, dask

I want to select rows from a dask dataframe based on a list of indices. How can I do that?

**Example:**
Let's say, I have the following dask dataframe.

```
dict_ = {'A':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'B':[2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'index':['x1', 'a2', 'x3', 'c4', 'x5', 'y6', 'x7']}
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dict_)
pdf = pdf.set_index('index')
ddf = dask.dataframe.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions = 2)
```

Furthermore, I have a list of indices, that I am interested in, e.g.

```
indices_i_want_to_select = ['x1','x3', 'y6']
```

From this, I would like to generate a dask dataframe containing only the rows specified in `indices_i_want_to_select`

Comment: `loc` on lists is not yet supported.  See https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1298

Comment: Thank you for this information. I do not insist on using loc, just any possible way to generate a dask dataframe based on a list of indices would be nice. Currently, I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: You should be able to hack something up with `map_partitions`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Edit: dask now supports loc on lists:

```
ddf_selected = ddf.loc[indices_i_want_to_select]
```

The following should still work, but is not necessary anymore:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

#generate example dataframe
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = [1,2,3,4,5], B = [6,7,8,9,0]), index=['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 4, 5])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions = 2)

#list of indices I want to select
l = ['i1', 4, 5]

#generate new dask dataframe containing only the specified indices
ddf_selected = ddf.map_partitions(lambda x: x[x.index.isin(l)], meta = ddf.dtypes)
```

Comment: For me this example returns an empty Series. This is the same problem I encountered in my own code. Am I missing something?

Comment: Aha, the difference is in applying the method to index or other column value. In case of other column value, simply use: `ddf_selected = ddf[ddf.B.isin(l)]`

Answer (score 2):

Using `dask` version '1.2.0' results with an error due to the mixed index type.
in any case there is an option to use `loc`.

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

#generate example dataframe
pdf = pd.DataFrame(dict(A = [1,2,3,4,5], B = [6,7,8,9,0]), index=['i1', 'i2', 'i3', '4', '5'])
ddf = dd.from_pandas(pdf, npartitions = 2,)

# #list of indices I want to select
l = ['i1', '4', '5']

# #generate new dask dataframe containing only the specified indices
# ddf_selected = ddf.map_partitions(lambda x: x[x.index.isin(l)], meta = ddf.dtypes)
ddf_selected = ddf.loc[l]
ddf_selected.head()
```