# How to select data with list of indexes from a partitioned DF (non-unique indexes)?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, dask

### Problem

I have a dataframe `df` with indexes not monotonically increasing over 4 partitions, meaning every partition is indexed with [0..N]. 
I need to select rows based on a indexes list [0..M] where M > N. 
Using `loc` would yield to an inconsistent output as there are multiple rows indexed by `0` (see example).

In other words, I'd need to overcome the difference between Dask's and Pandas' [reset_index](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.reset_index), as it'd easily solve my issue.

### Example

`print df.loc[0].compute()` results in:

```
   Unnamed: 0  best_answer  thread_id  ty_avc    ty_ber  ty_cjr  ty_cpc  \
0           0            1          1       1  0.052174       9      18   
0           0            1       5284      12  0.039663      34      60   
0           0            1      18132       2  0.042254       7      20   
0           0            1      44211       4  0.025000       5       5
```

### Possible solutions

1. repartition `df` to 1 single partition and `reset_index`, don't like as won't fit in memory;
2. add a column with [0..M] indexes and use [set_index](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index), discouraged in [performance tips](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-performance.html#avoid-shuffles);
3. solution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318136/how-can-i-select-data-from-a-dask-dataframe-by-a-list-of-indices) solves a different problem as his df has unique indexes;
4. split the indexes list in `npartitions` parts, apply offset computation and use `map_partitions`

I cannot think of other solutions... probably the last one is more efficient although not sure if it's actually feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally Dask.dataframe does not track the lengths of the pandas dataframes that make up the dask.dataframe.  I suspect that your option 4 is best.  You might also consider using [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html)

See also http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed-collections.html

Comment: Indeed [dask.delayed](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/delayed.html) is a good way to go, turns out to be fast enough.